# Unable to download files when target set to Android 10 API level 29 in xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, storage, android-10.0

[image]Working with xamarin forms and changed Target Android Version to Android 10.0 API level 29. I am downloading pdf ZIP files from server and saving in External Storage. So this works fine till Android 9. but in Android 10 devices unable to download content. i added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest.xml . now i am able to create directory with package name in external storage. so i gave this path to download manager. when download manager starts downloading it shown java.lang.securityException. and message is unsupported path.

```
string extension = FetchFileExtension(downloadPath.ContentUrl.ContentType);
                        string path = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get<Interfaces.IPath>().InternalStoragePath(), productId + extension);
                        IDownloadManager downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;
                        downloadManager.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
                        {
                            return path;
                        });
                        FetchLaunchData(productId);
                        IDownloadFile downloadFile = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(downloadPath.ContentUrl.Offline);
                        _activeDownloads[productId] = downloadFile;
                        downloadFile.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedEventHandler;
                        downStartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                        downloadManager.Start(downloadFile);
    public string StoragePath()
    {
        
        return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/." + Assets.AppConst.ApplicationId + "/";
    }
```

Comment: Android 10 (API level 29) introduces a number of features and behavior changes to better protect users' privacy. Check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: @blackapps please check now

Comment: We cannot see which path you use. So there is little to say.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Hi thanks for response. yes as of my last 48hrs research i got know there is difference in API 29. i seen lot of documentations but everything is for java or kotlin. i am working with xamarin forms(c#). main aim is to store documents in external or internal storage when target android version is Android 10 in xamarin forms project.

Comment: @blackapps i tried two paths. one is internal storage: data/data/com.myapp.mobile/files/filename.extension        secoond tried is external storage path: i am creating directory with my package name i.e, storage/emulated/0/com.myapp.mobile/filename.extension

Comment: Those are invalid paths. Both paths should start with a /.

Comment: yes they are starting with / only. i just typed in comment erlier comments not copied exact paths. there is no problem in path.In  Android 10 they introduced secure storage(or scopped storage). so we cant able to access storage in android 10 devices. for that in native android there is a solution. but i didnt find any solution for xamarin forms or xamarin native. For native android in java : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: If you can add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to manifest file then the second path should work with xamarin too. Would be bad if not.